# Database query within actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem, I'll simplify it down to the blog example.

1. Each 'post' is created by a different user stored in a 'User' database.
2. Several 'comments' belong to the one 'post'.
3. When a new 'comment' is made, the user who created the initial 'post' needs to be emailed.

I have setup the mailer and observer. I am just not sure how to get the user of the post's email address once a new post is made.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have associations set up like this

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Then in your mailer just find the user's e-mail address through these associations

```
class CommentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def comment_notification(comment)
    recipients comment.post.user.email
    # Other mail sending methods
  end
end
```

And once new comment is being created

```
comment = Comment.create(attributes)
CommentMailer.deliver_comment_notification(comment)
```